# Organizing millions of images like twitter

Tags: php, image-processing, twitter, architecture

I wanted to understand how twitter store images in their system, I tried changing my profile picture and here are results

```
first (old image):
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/630016855789342722/txe37Y0U_bigger.jpg
second:
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/877043179630903296/dX2qEpEn_bigger.jpg
third:
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/877043710835347458/Zkms42gZ_bigger.jpg
```

I see `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/` is their static CDN path, then comes a random number then image name (randomstring + _ + size.jpg).

```
CDNPath/incrementedNumber/randomString.jpg
```

what I am not getting here is how they are generating this `incrementedNumber`
to store images.

Comment: it's probably just an incremented number - but grouped for every user on twitter.  So each directory may have (for example) a 1000 images, this means as it fills up from everyone updating images, the next directory is generated.

Comment: This is a system generated directory with random numbers. so user image wouldn't be overwrite if same name as ofcourse there are thousands of images in single server.

Comment: answers to this questions can only be guessed...

Comment: I dont think its a random number, I try changing my profile images multiple times and its always an incremented number .

Comment: @Piglet you are right until and unless someone from twitter answer this question.

Comment: yes and as this is not going to happen your question does not meet the criteria metioned here [ask]

Comment: who says it cant happen ?, and I am not after exactly their solution but similar solution to my problem statement .

Answer (score 1):

For generating IDs, Twitter uses a scheme called [Snowflake](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake.html).

That is *probably* how they are generating your profile image ID.

Comment: This is an interesting article however they do mentioned that they are not currently using it in production mode.

Comment: The article is from 2010. They are using it in production now.